# Converting list to terms in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, type-conversion

I have to implement the predicate `cons(List, Term)` that will take a list `[Head|Tail]` and convert it to terms, represented as `next(Head, Tail)`. How do I do this? I don't even know where to start.

Here is the example of a successful query given in the question:

```
cons([a,b,c],X).  /*query returns X=next(a,next(b,next(c,null))).*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing most anything with lists will require that you consider two cases: the empty list and a list with a head and a sublist. Usually your base case is handling the empty list and your inductive case is handling the list with sublist.

First consider your base case:

```
cons([], null).
```

Now deal with your inductive case:

```
cons([X|Xs], next(X, Rest)) :- cons(Xs, Rest).
```