# How do I write a predicate that converts terms to lists?

Tags: prolog

I have to implement the predicate `next(Integer, List)` that will take a list represented as terms `next(int,List)` , and convert it to `List[Head|Tail]` Representation. How do I do this? Ive been trying forever but cant find any help how to do this.(nil is the empty list)

```
ex:
next(1,nill) = [1]
next(4,next(3,next(2,next(1,nill)))) = [4,3,2,1]
next(22,next(11,next(9,next(6,next(3,next(2,next(5,nill))))))) = [22,11,9,6,3,2,5]
```

Comment: What have you tried? `next(N, A)` is converted into the list `[N|T]` if `A` can be converted into `T`. Can you write this statement in prolog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have found the solution, but have not recognized it.

If you look at the solution from [Converting list to terms in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296847/converting-list-to-terms-in-prolog) :

```
cons([], null).
cons([X|Xs], next(X, Rest)) :- cons(Xs, Rest).
```

If you ask how the list `[a, b, c]` is converted it gives:

```
| ?- cons([a, b, c], X).

X = next(a,next(b,next(c,null)))
```

Now you can just ask it in reverse, what is the list which gives the term `next(a,next(b,next(c,null)))`:

```
| ?- cons(X, next(a,next(b,next(c,null)))).

X = [a,b,c] ? 

yes
```

Similarly for your examples:

```
| ?- cons(X, next(4,next(3,next(2,next(1,null))))).

X = [4,3,2,1] ? 

yes
| ?- cons(X, next(22,next(11,next(9,next(6,next(3,next(2,next(5,null)))))))).

X = [22,11,9,6,3,2,5] ? 

yes
```

PS: I have used `null` instead of `nill`.

Comment: thank this is exactly what i was looking for!, is there anyway I can reverse how i check the list in cons
```
ex:
| ?- cons(next(4,next(3,next(2,next(1,null)))), X).

X = [4,3,2,1] ? ```

Comment: @ragsa: Just reverse the arguments in the definition itself  `cons(next(X, Rest), [X|Xs]) :- cons(Rest, Xs).`  and `cons(null, []).`

Comment: @ragsa: **Or** you can define a new predicate say `cons1(X, Y) :- cons(Y, X).` and then use `cons1`.